# Performance issue while separation small amount of tables to different schemas

Tags: sql-server, performance, database-schema

Assume that we have a database on MS SQL Server 2008 with 20-30 tables at the core of our distributed system. Permissions to read and write these tables can vary for each layer of our system. 
For example, we have three types of clients, that could connect to our database directly or via some intermediate layer. To eliminate the possibility of incorrect operations we have to correctly set the permissions for each type of client. 
The obvious solution is to separate our tables to different SQL Server schemas and set permissions to access objects in schema as a whole. And now we must decide how justified this solution on relatively small amount of tables and how it will impact on performance (it seeems that very often we must to join tables from different schemas).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Joining tables from different schemas will not affect performance.
But, actually, it is better to grant permissions on procedures not on tables.

Comment: You mean, that placing all the tables in dbo scheme and separating the procedures like InsertTable1, UpdateTable1, DeleteTable1 and ShowTable1 view to different schemas would be better?

Comment: Of course, It depends on your situation, but generally it is better grant permissions on procedures, because if you give `select` permission on some table user can easily copy all the data, if you give `update` or `delete` permission he can easily spoil all the data. Also, you can rarely decide that only particular group of users can access some table. For example, not only customers need access to Orders table but also suppliers and managers. But it is better include tables in some schema if you see any logic in it, so it will be easier work with them.